# Interfacing managed c# out variable to unmanaged, native C++

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

**Background**

Hi all. I don't have a significant amount of c++ experience, but I have a lot of experience in other languages.

What I am trying to accomplish is create wrappers for a C# library to be used in a native C++ application. What I have so far is a C++/CLI wrapper that exposes many of the functions in the C# library so that I can use them in my native C++ application. I have done so in a way like what is demonstrated here:

http://pragmateek.com/using-c-from-native-c-with-the-help-of-ccli-v2/

**Question**

I am having an issue passing a managed C++/CLI pointer to the C# library. The function in the C# library looks like this:

```
public bool SomeFunction(out byte[] buffer)
```

For some reason I am having a hard time passing a pointer to this variable in my C++/CLI wrapper. The function is requesting a managed reference but the & doesn't work on managed references, and I can't seem to get it working by using % either.

I need to grab the byte array from the function, and I am pretty certain I can marshal the data into a type my C++ code can handle. Any suggestions?

**Edit**: Removed the unclear reference to the C++/CLI code. In response to Hans, I was referencing the C# library successfully, because I have been able to pass data back and forth from the C# library to the native C++ code. Also, I didn't intend for this to sound so mysterious. The C# library is for a microscope camera that I am trying to interface with Micromanager. The particular function I am working on has to do with grabbing the data from the image buffer.

**Update**

Thanks to Lucas, I have a solution. For whatever reason I thought I needed to pass a pointer to the C# library in my C++/CLI library. My final code for the C++/CLI wrapper was:

```
public: bool SomeFunction(unsigned char* cBuffer, int* count) {
    cli::array<unsigned char>^ buffer;
    bool isFull = _referenceToManagedCSharpClass->SomeFunction(buffer);
    pin_ptr<unsigned char> pinnedArray = &buffer[0];
    cBuffer = pinnedArray;
    *count = buffer->Length;
    return isFull;
}
```

It's still not clear why I didn't need to pass a pointer to the C# library, or why I need to use the pin_ptr to store the pointer in cBuffer, but I think I will figure this out with reading. Thanks to everyone that helped me with this.

Comment: It is *very* unclear why you posted the C++/CLI declaration of this method.  You should never write it yourself since it exists in the C# library.  Your C++/CLI project must add a reference to the C# library.

Comment: My apologies for it being unclear. As I stated, I am relatively new to C++. As I also stated above, I have to write an interface to expose the C# library to native C++ (which is not C++/CLI). I posted the C++/CLI since that was the point of reference given to me in the SDK, and I figured that was a starting point for exposing this particular C# function in C++/CLI (since the SDK C++/CLI has been a good starting point for every other function I have already incorporated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have the following class:

```cpp
ref class SomeClass
{
public:
    static bool SomeFunction([System::Runtime::InteropServices::OutAttribute] array<unsigned char>^% buffer)
    {
        buffer = gcnew array<unsigned char> { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' };
        return true;
    }
};
```

It could be implemented in C#, this doesn't matter as long as you can access it from C++/CLI (add a reference [as Hans said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555569#comment54891378_33555569)).

To get the output value, you simply do the following:

```cpp
array<unsigned char>^ clrArray;
SomeClass::SomeFunction(clrArray);
```

`clrArray` will be set to the value returned by `SomeFunction` from the `out` parameter.

If you want to access the raw bytes from native C++, you need to *pin* the array. As long as it's pinned, you're safe to reference the buffer. Here's an example:

Assuming you have the following native function:

```cpp
void NativeFunc(unsigned char *data, size_t count)
{
    std::copy(data, data + count, std::ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(std::cout, ""));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

You can call:

```cpp
pin_ptr<unsigned char> pinnedArray = &clrArray[0];
NativeFunc(pinnedArray, clrArray->Length);
```

You have to consider the data pointer as invalid after `pinnedArray` goes out of scope. It may get relocated by the GC at any time. If you need pinning for longer periods of time, use a pinned `GCHandle`, but this is more heavyweight.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion of defining clrArray, and then using it with the C# library. Won't I have to marshal this (since array is cli::array) to get it into C++? If this is the case, then the method I was trying to use to cycle through the entries to marshal the data wasn't working because I was getting an error when trying to use clrArray.Count. I will have to try your last method tomorrow. I tried a variation of it using the pin_ptr, but I think I may have gotten it wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're right when you cay you can't use a `cli::array` *directly* from C++. You have two solutions: you can marshal the array (which just means you copy its contents to a native buffer), or you can take a pointer to the data like I did in the answer. This works without the copy overhead, you just have to make sure it stays pinned.

Comment: Ah, okay. I misread your answer then. Okay, it looks like I was using Count instead of Length when I tried something like this to begin with. One residual question I have is why I don't need to pass a pointer to the C# function. Again, my apologies on the ignorance.

Comment: Well, you already pass a reference to the C# function - it's a pointer in disguise :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Light bulb is on.